# Is there a protocol to cluster observed behaviour data?

Tags: social-psychology, behavior, behaviorism

I have observed a number of users in 3 public parks during the course of 2 months and have identified 60 different types of uses. I can't find a protocol to classify similar uses (not users) into clusters. I know that I should do it manually, and I do believe it is not a complex task, but I would like to follow some basic rules and I cannot find a good source. Could anyone suggest me an author?

Comment: Thematic coding, as a method to systematically identify recurring uses, comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks Steven! My question is done after your response and I got some nice sources to investigate.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to answer your own question. 

Comment: Closing as [answered in comments](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2163/7001).